# How to get ipywidgets working in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter, ipywidgets, jupyter-lab

In Jupyter Notebook, ipywidgets work fine, however they seem to not work in Jupyter Lab (which is supposedly better than Notebook).

I followed these [directions](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Using%20Interact.html).

**Step 1:** Installed Node.js  (https://nodejs.org/en/)

**Step 2:** Installed requirements on Python 3 with conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

Unfortunately, basic widgets do not work inside the jupyter lab notebook:

[image]

Comment: It's useful to look at the browser's javascript console as well

Comment: What versions were you trying?

Comment: Did you restart the kernel if it was already running?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

JupyterLab now prefers a model where [arbitrary javascript is no longer allowed](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3118) to be embedded in a cell's output, which is how many interactive Jupyter Notebook modules used to work. They now ask that [modules with interactivity create a JupyterLab extension](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3748).
ipywidgets provides `@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager` extension which satisfies this requirement.

When using ipywidgets 7.6 or newer in JupyterLab 3.0 or newer you do not need to do anything: it is [installed by default](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html#installing-in-jupyterlab-3-0). You can check if this is installed by running:

```
jupyter labextension list
```

which should include a line like:

```
@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager v3.0.0 enabled OK (python, jupyterlab_widgets)
```

If you are using JupyterLab 1 or 2 (or old version of ipywidgets) you need to install this extension [manually](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html#installing-into-jupyterlab-1-or-2) by running this on your command line (which assumes you already have [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) installed):

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

Comment: This also solved the following error for qgrid not displaying, but only showing `QgridWidget(grid_options={'fullWidthRows': True, 'syncColumnCellResize': True,`. I have added as a comment  to make it easier to find, as none of the other solutions to this error worked for me. Thanks

Comment: Didn't work for me - Error: Object 'jupyter.widget' not found in registry

Comment: I had to run this command twice. Both times output was identical - no errors. Pretty sure I restarted everything properly, but who knows. Bizarre. YMMV.

Comment: For me, `@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager` was not installed by default (using mini-forge conda). Pressing install through Jupyter Lab extension manager fixed it.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same pbm, and tried this solution (hope it can help others):

The `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager` gave this kind of error in my case:

```
> /Users/user/.nvm/versions/node/v8.7.0/bin/npm pack @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
jupyter-widgets-jupyterlab-manager-0.35.0.tgz

Errored, use --debug for full output:
ValueError:
"@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@0.35.0" is not compatible with the current JupyterLab
Conflicting Dependencies:
JupyterLab              Extension            Package
>=0.15.4-0 <0.16.0-0    >=0.16.0-0 <0.17.0-0 @jupyterlab/application
>=1.1.4-0 <2.0.0-0      >=2.0.0-0 <3.0.0-0   @jupyterlab/services
>=0.15.4-0 <0.16.0-0    >=0.16.0-0 <0.17.0-0 @jupyterlab/rendermime
>=0.15.4-0 <0.16.0-0    >=0.16.0-0 <0.17.0-0 @jupyterlab/notebook
```

Then, what I did is to use a previous version 0.34 instead of 0.35:
`jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@0.34`

In fact, according to [this](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/1855), sometime teams get time to consider the last version.

UP (according to comments):
You can check `jupyter lab --version` and find match on [its version compatibility](https://npm.taobao.org/package/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager).

And it works now !

[image]

Comment: One may check the version `jupyter lab --version` and find match on this [version compatibility](https://npm.taobao.org/package/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager).

Comment: This comment is my favorite answer :).

Comment: Didn't work for me - Error: Object 'jupyter.widget' not found in registry

Comment: This works for me, big thanks! Seems that the issue is related to packages version dependencies.

Answer (score 11):

Had the same issue, and what worked for me today was running the 'clean' command, as mentioned here: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html#installing-the-jupyterlab-extension

So:

```
jupyter lab clean
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

And that got it working right for me just now.

Comment: Yep! As of 10/2022, JupyterLab 3.x, this was the way to solve it.

Answer (score 9):

**Note: most of the above answers are outdated (as of july 19 2021)**. It should be a lot more seamless with the latest versions of these packages. However, in 2021 I was having an issue rendering `panel` widgets in jupyterlab hosted on jupyterhub and came across this post. I tried a few of these answers at first but none of them worked. After digging into some of the libraries, I found the following:

1. `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager` is no longer required as of `ipywidgets==7.6` and `jupyterlab>=3.0`. [source](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/master/docs/source/changelog.md#76). If you're on the latest version of jupyterlab, you should just need to install `ipywidgets` and the extension will be enabled automatically as long as widget extension authors also [follow some steps](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/master/docs/source/changelog.md#updates-for-widget-maintainers).

   > The main change in this release is that installing ipywidgets 7.6.0 will now automatically enable ipywidgets support in JupyterLab 3.0—a user has no extra JupyterLab installation step and no rebuild of JupyterLab, nor do they need Node.js installed. Simply install the python ipywidgets package with pip (pip install ipywidgets==7.6.0) or conda/mamba (conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets=7.6.0) and ipywidgets will automatically work in classic Jupyter Notebook and in JupyterLab 3.0.
2. `panel` has also followed suit and bundled the necessary extensions in the `pyviz_comms` package, so theoretically everything should have been included for my case. [source](https://pypi.org/project/panel/)

   > In the classic Jupyter notebook environment and JupyterLab, first make sure to load the pn.extension(). Panel objects will then render themselves if they are the last item in a notebook cell. For versions of jupyterlab>=3.0 the necessary extension is automatically bundled in the pyviz_comms package, which must be >=2.0.

The answer to my problem turned out to be that I was installing `panel` *after* building the jupyterlab server through jupyterhub. (e.g. for a specific notebook, a user was running `!pip install panel`). This is where I get a little fuzzy since I'm not sure why this doesn't work, given that `ipywidgets` is already installed and `panel` install includes the pre-built jupyterlab extension. However, I was able to fix my issue by instead using an a jupyterlab image to spawn from jupyterhub which had `ipywidgets>=7.6` and `panel>=0.11.3` (and therefore `pyviz_comms>=2.0`) pre-installed. After this, panel widgets in jupyterlab on jupyterhub now work. Hope this helps anybody having a similar issue.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue as @jtlz2 that none of the above suggestion works for me except @hainm's very specific version combination for jupyter-lab, ipywidgests, and jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager.

Following the initial version numbers listed in this post (https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2488#issuecomment-509719214), I tried to find the most updated version combination that works. I list them below, such that one can try it if there is really nothing else working for him/her.

```sh
pythonversion=3.8.0
labversion=2.1.5
labmanagerversion=2.0
ipywidgetsversion=7.5.1
nodejsversion=10.13.0

conda create -n lab python=$pythonversion -y
source activate lab
conda install nodejs=$nodejsversion -c conda-forge -y
conda install ipywidgets=$ipywidgetsversion -c conda-forge -y
conda install jupyterlab=$labversion  -y -c conda-forge
jupyter-labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@$labmanagerversion
```

It seems that the version of nodejs plays a key role. Holing everything else equal, if I update nodejsversion to 12.x+ or the latest 14.x, this combination as well as @hainm's combination both fail to make ipywidgets behave normally in Jupyterlab.

Other than the one I listed in the above code cell, below 6 combinations also work for me.

(pythonversion ,labversion ,labmanagerversion ,ipywidgets ,nodejsversion)

1. (3.7 , 0.34 , 0.37 , 7.4.2 , 10.13)
2. (3.7 , 1.0 , 1.0 , 7.4.2 , 10.13)
3. (3.7 , 2.0 , 2.0 , 7.4.2 , 10.13)
4. (3.8 , 2.0 , 2.0 , 7.4.2 , 10.13)
5. (3.8 , 2.0 , 2.0 , 7.5.1 , 10.13)
6. (3.8 , 2.1.5 , 2.0 , 7.5.1 , 10.13)

Answer (score 3):

I was getting a `Permission Denied` error, so adding `sudo` to the accepted command helped: `sudo jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [ipywidgets.readthedocs.io](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io) documentation ([Installing the JupyterLab Extension](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html#installing-the-jupyterlab-extension)), for "*JupyterLab*" do the following steps in "*Anaconda Prompt*".

**Step 1**

```
conda install -c conda-forge nodejs
```

**Step 2**

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides everything else, **make sure that your ipywidgets are installed in the same conda environment as jupyterlab**.

Here is my story (ipywidgets 7.7.0, jupyterlab 3.2.5 installed via conda inside docker):

1. Running dockerized `jupyterlab` in base conda environment
2. Created new conda environment, install `ipykernel`, make it visible to `jupyterlab`, install `ipywidgets`
3. Switch to new kernel, now `jupyterlab` recognized `ipywidgets` as installed, but widgets are not working (only displays text widget description), which is confusing

Solution:

- Install ipywidgets in the same conda environment as jupyterlab

Disclaimer: My answer may not be applicable to the original question, since the author did not use separate conda environment. But it can be useful for others facing similar problem.

Comment: this answer is under-rated

Answer (score 1):

***None of the other answers worked to me. It all seems to be down to version compatibility. Finally got it working - see below.
All credit to @hainm on github (original link: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2488#issuecomment-509719214)
My SO answer on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60059786/1021819
Here is a straight copy of that answer:***

Leveraging https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2488#issuecomment-509719214, in a jupyterlab terminal - running on jupyterhub - execute:

```
pythonversion=3.7
labversion=0.34.12
labmanagerversion=0.37.4
ipywidgetsversion=7.4.2

conda install ipywidgets=$ipywidgetsversion -c conda-forge -y --override-channels -c main
conda install jupyterlab=$labversion  -y -c conda-forge --override-channels -c main
jupyter-labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager@$labmanagerversion
```

At this point a `jupyter lab clean; jupyter lab build` might be of interest.

Then in a .ipynb notebook running in the same jupyterlab window, hit the restart kernel button.

**IMPORTANT:** Don't forget to also **REFRESH** the browser page - or all efforts will have been in vain . :\

Then execute the example:

```py
from ipywidgets import interact

@interact(x=(0, 100, 10))
def p(x=50):
    pass
```

I never thought I would live to see the day but - hey presto - the widget finally appears!

The sad things are that the setup is extremely sensitive to the installation of other extensions and the combination of compatible versions is very specific.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're on linux and **you'd rather avoid conda entirely**, and use virtual envs (venvs) to keep python happy, AND you happen to be using an 'older'/LTS Debian based OS, which may not have upto date nodejs: Ie, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, which doesn't have a `node` but rather `nodejs` (`node` belongs to another package, and the 'legacy nodejs' version is too old), then read on.

This *is* a little more complicated to setup, but much easier to maintain long-term than conda is. (you can always just mk a new `venv` for a new project, without breaking your old projects).

Main points are:

- use PPA's to get fresh versions of the things you need
- Use virtualenvwrapper so you can:

  - use up-to-date python3
  - avoid messing up your 'pip install''s
  - avoid getting the system package manager confused
  - also easily work with people with different versions of python
  - follow python Best Practise
  - easily have different venvs which might have old or incompatible python and pip packages.
- Use [Nodejs binary distributions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions)

  - need node.js version "10.x" for jupyterlab widgets
  - allows using the system's package manager to keep nodejs fresh
  - will be maintained and available as long as LTS's are

So, all actual steps (these were tested to work on Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia, which is basically compatible with ubuntu xenial aka Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Differences will arise mostly in nodejs, read the readme in the github link above to solve for other OS):

Get an admin to do (or do yourself if you can sudo):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y python3.8 python3.8-dev python3.8-distutils python3-pip python3-venv
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Then, as your own user, you can complete the rest of the steps:

```
pip3 install --user virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
mkdir ~/.envs
```

You'll then want to add the following to the end of your `.bashrc` :

```
export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
export WORKON_HOME=~/.envs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3
source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

At this point, make a new shell, and you will be able to run the rest of the setup, actually installing jupyterlab:

```
mkvirtualenv -p python3.8 jupenv
pip install jupyter matplotlib pandas ipympl tqdm
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

Now you're done.

To open/use jupyter, you want (because of the venv I've called `jupenv` above, you can name it as you like in that `mkvirtualenv` line):

```
workon jupenv
jupyter lab
```

Otherwise, I had no end of hell trying to get nodejs to work with outdated ubuntu packages. Sometimes it would work, for a few restarts, and then fail. Other times it would just keep giving me the same missing widgets, or sometimes little lines of junk js code.

Virtualenvs are well worth using, especially when you start using python seriously, and working with others who may use different versions / different sets of pip packages. [VirtualEnvWrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) makes this pretty painless.
The basic point is that everything you 'pip install', even jupyter, ends up being kept cleanly separate (and separate from the system packages), which keeps everything working very nicely.

There are some basic DO's and DON'T's:

- DON'T run `pip install ...` lines without being in a venv
- DON'T use `pip3` in place of `pip` within a venv.
- DO just use `python` and not `python3` to run within.
- DON'T use `conda...`!
- DO know that you can have all your virtualenvs updated at once with:

  - `allvirtualenv pip install -U pip`

As for the nodejs binary distribution packages: These are highly recommended where they support your particular OS. They'll be very up-to-date and should present the minimum of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Please check steps to make it work in Jupyter 3.0 [docs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html#installing-in-jupyterlab-3-0)

Please check steps to make it work in Jupyter 1 0r 2 [docs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_install.html#installing-into-jupyterlab-1-or-2)

After this restart or build the lab to see the changes