# Interactive Jupyter Widgets not working in Jupyter Lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I noticed that [interactive widgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html) are not working in my Jupyter Lab notebooks.

The following code should produce an interactive slider but doesn't:

```
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets

def f(x):
    return x

interact(f, x=10);
```

[image]

What is the problem here, and how can I get widgets to work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ipywidgets working in Jupyter Lab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49542417/how-to-get-ipywidgets-working-in-jupyter-lab)

Answer (score 6):

You need to install widget extension

```
pip install ipywidgets
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension --sys-prefix
```

Comment: `!>  jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension --sys-prefix                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              117ms < Tue Oct  2 12:26:48 2018
Error executing Jupyter command 'nbextension': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: This is not fixing it.

Answer (score 4):

Per the [docs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html):

*To install the JupyterLab extension you also need to run the command below in a terminal **which requires that you have nodejs installed**.*

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager
```

I think it's the latter nodejs requirement that you are missing e.g. with Conda, first run:

```
conda install nodejs
```

Comment: Didn't work for me - Error: Object 'jupyter.widget' not found in registry

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

delete all output cells

save notebook

reload page

restart kernel

run with %matplotlib widget

Comment: This is an old post you've now tagged with a more current answer. (ipywidgets no long needs nodejs or a separate command to trigger the extension to be useful in current Jupyter.) Thanks. I'm a bit unsure though if `%matplotlib widget` is really needed though? As discussed [here that is related to using interactive plots with ipympl](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/#basic-example). I don't see why ipywidgets would need a magic command that set the matplotlib backend?