# Jupyter Lab - dask-labextension not working

Tags: python, jupyter, dask, jupyter-lab

Jupyter Lab [dask-labextension](https://github.com/dask/dask-labextension) not working

**Installed** both from:

- A.) JupyterLab side bar/ Extension manager/ search for it / click install
- B.) Command line rom my cd to anaconda [installation guide](https://github.com/dask/dask-labextension)

```
conda install jupyterlab nodejs
conda install -c conda-forge dask-labextension
jupyter labextension install dask-labextension
jupyter serverextension enable dask_labextension
```

**ERROR**

- In juyerlab start up pop up error message - `ERROR: "Dask Server Error Failed to list clusters: might the server extension not be installed/enabled?"`
- Than if I wait it offers me to make a build -> I click `build`
- `Build CompleteBuild successfully completed, reload page?` click -> `reload`

**Question**

- I have Token password locked my JupyterLab can that be the reason that this extension can not access it?

**Tried Solutions**

- Deleting extension from JupyterLab side bar/ Extension manager

  - `WARNING The JupyterLab development team is excited to have a robust third-party extension community. However, we do not review third-party extensions, and some extensions may introduce security risks or contain malicious code that runs on your machine.`
  - `Error communicating with server extension. Consult the documentation for how to ensure that it is enabled. Reason given: Error: 403 (Forbidden)`
- I have node js installed - https://stackoverflow.com/a/55450973/10270590

Comment: The code here works for me (both w/ JupyterLab 3 and older), could you please share the jupyterlab and dask versions you're using? Also, if it's an older version, do you have ipywidgets and bokeh installed correctly?

Comment: Related question on how to remove dask-labextension: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76399039/ho-to-remove-uninstall-dask-labextension-from-jupyterlab/76399140#76399140

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JupyterLab 3.0 has been released since this question was posted, and it makes installing extensions much easier. If you have dask distributed installed, you can: `conda/pip install dask-labextension`

Comment: Hi, I see this is your first answer. However as this isn't an actual answer and you are instead helping to debug, this should be a commend on the question. You can post those once you earn enough reputation.