# How to remove/uninstall dask-labextension from JupyterLab?

Tags: dask, jupyter-lab

When starting JupyterLab, I get an annoing popup message from dask-labextension:

```
"Dask Server Error"

Failed to list Dask clusters: might the servers extension not be installed/enabled?
```

I do not need dask and would like to remove it.

I tried

```
jupyter labextension uninstall dask-labextension
```

and got

```
JupyterLab cannot uninstall this extension. Use your Python package manager (pip, conda, etc.) to uninstall the package dask_labextension
```

Then I tried

```
pip uninstall dask_labextension
```

and

```
pip uninstall dask-labextension
```

but got a WARNING, that the package is not installed, e.g.

```
WARNING: Skipping dask_labextension as it is not installed.
```

The extension is listed in the extension manager:

[image]

However, the entry in the extension manager does not provide options to **uninstall** or disable the extension.

Listing pip packages using

```
pip list
```

I saw following packages related to dask:

```
dask                          2022.12.0
dask-image                    2022.9.0
dask-searchcv                 0.2.0
```

Trying to uninstall with

```
pip uninstall dask 
pip uninstall dask-image
pip uninstall dask-searchcv
jupyter lab build
```

did not help.

Related question:

[Jupyter Lab - dask-labextension not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64500809/jupyter-lab-dask-labextension-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to disable it with

```
jupyter labextension disable dask-labextension
```

and then deleted the folder

```
C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\Python\share\jupyter\labextensions\dask-labextension
```

Comment: (note that "labextension" is going away as a command in newer jlab)