# How to tell if the environment is Jupyter Notebook vs Jupyterlab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I've got a Python module that supports a Jupyter frontend using Ipywidgets. This works fine in Jupyter Notebook, but fails silently in Jupyterlab, because they apparently [don't allow arbitrary Javascript anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49542417/how-to-get-ipywidgets-working-in-jupyter-lab). There is an Ipywidgets extension for Jupyterlab, but it wouldn't be obvious to the user that they need to do that, so I'd like to display a message if the current context is a Jupyterlab environment and the extension isn't installed. Something like this:

```
def isIpy():
    try:
        __IPYTHON__
        return True
    except NameError: return False

if is_ipy():
    if <is_jupyterlab()> and not <has_widgets_extension()>: print('Use \'jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager\' to install the widgets extension')
    else: launchIpyWidgets() #This works fine
else: launchTkinterWidgets() #This also works fine
```

Alternatively – and perhaps preferably – I could place a check in the widget display:

```
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import interactive, Layout, Accordion, HBox, VBox, HTML, Label, Button, FloatProgress
postinstruct = Label(value='After setting parameter values, run launchPlots() or start() to start the model.')
display(postinstruct)

if <failed to display>: print('Use \'jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager\' to install the widgets extension')
```

The problem being that, in Jupyterlab, it won't return an error, or display the widget; it'll just display the text `Label(value='Use…')`.

Any idea how to reliably check either of these things?