# Google Colabs eval_js in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Is there some way to get the behavior of `google.colab.output.eval_js` in a Jupyter Notebook? I have a bit of Code that uses `IPython.display` to let the user draw an image. When a button is pressed, JS saves the content of the image as `data` and I then use `data = eval_js("data")` in Python to pull that content into Python. I am trying to replicate that behavior in a Jupyter Notebook. I put the full Code below.

---

```
from IPython.display import HTML, Image
from google.colab.output import eval_js

canvas_html = """
<canvas width=%d height=%d style="background-color:rgb(240,240,240)"=></canvas>
<button>Guess Number</button>
<script>
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.lineWidth = %d
var button = document.querySelector('button')
var mouse = {x: 0, y: 0}
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  mouse.x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft
  mouse.y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop
})
canvas.onmousedown = ()=>{
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.moveTo(mouse.x, mouse.y)
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onPaint)
}
canvas.onmouseup = ()=>{
  canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', onPaint)
}
var onPaint = ()=>{
  ctx.lineTo(mouse.x, mouse.y)
  ctx.stroke()
}
var data = new Promise(resolve=>{
  button.onclick = ()=>{
    resolve(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'))
  }
})
</script>
"""

def draw(filename='drawing.png', w=280, h=280, line_width=20):
  display(HTML(canvas_html % (w, h, line_width)))
  data = eval_js("data")
  # do sth with the variable in python ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Go for `pip install Js2Py`

then,

`from js2py import eval_js`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [#64103409](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64103409/from-google-colab-import-files-how-to-get-the-same-behaviour-of-files-in-jupyte), you can actually see how [`eval_js`](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/0e3c20fb16bf1891d62b4db67645902a843e186a/google/colab/output/_js.py#L23) is implemented.  You'll see a reference to [`_ipython`](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/0e3c20fb16bf1891d62b4db67645902a843e186a/google/colab/_ipython.py#L23), which is a `ipykernel.ipkernel.IPythonKernel` object in Jupyter Notebook, JupyterLab, and even Azure ML's notebooks (which use per-cell sandboxing).  Similarly, [`_message`](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/main/google/colab/_message.py) is responsible for sending and receiving messages.

The problem is that this Python code sends a [`collab_request`](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/0e3c20fb16bf1891d62b4db67645902a843e186a/google/colab/_message.py#L145) message to the client, and that's probably a non-standard message added by an extension that won't work on stock JupyterLab or Jupyter Notebook.

Jupyter Notebook (but not JupyterLab) allows for fairly headache-free communication between Python and the browser using the [comms](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/comms.html) interface.  JupyterLab went the other direction and [no longer supports scripting outside the context of extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49613135/7077511).  So right now, it's pretty much deliberately difficult to write a solution that works everywhere.