# from google.colab import files, how to get the same behaviour of files in Jupyterlab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm currently working on a project that runs fine on colab, but I would like to modify and run it on my local jupyterlab but there are some functions on that project that are specific to colab like `files` and `output` imported this way `from google.colab import files` and `from google.colab import output`.

I will appreciate if you have a way to go about solving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I found [it](https://pypi.org/project/google-colab/#description) on pypi, so basically you can install the module locally `pip install google-colab`and then use it in your notebook.

Also here you can find the repo with the desired modules: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/tree/0162530b8c7f76741ee3e518db34aa5c173e8ebe/google/colab

Comment: Hi @dejdej, thank you for the answer, but this installation lead to an other problem with the package `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termios'` that is only available on Linux only :(