# alternatives to eval_js (in Google Colab) for Jupyter Notebooks(Binder)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory, ros, jupyter-lab

I am trying to connect Jupyter Notebook (provided by **Binder**) with ROS in my laptop using rosbridge server from `rosbridge_suite`.

Previously I was able to connect it to Google Colab by using following script(using `roslibjs`),

```
from IPython.display import Javascript, display
from google.colab import output

display(Javascript(url="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/roslib@1/build/roslib.js"))

output.eval_js('''

// Connecting to ROS
// -----------------

var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
  url : 'ws://localhost:9090'
});

ros.on('connection', function() {
  console.log('Connected to websocket server Hi da.');
});

ros.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log('Error connecting to websocket server: ', error);
});

ros.on('close', function() {
  console.log('Connection to websocket server closed.');
});

// Subscribing to a Topic
var listener = new ROSLIB.Topic({
  ros : ros,
  name : '/Geomagic/joint_states',
  messageType : 'sensor_msgs/JointState'
});

listener.subscribe(function(message) {
  console.log('Received message on ' + listener.name + ': ' + message.position);
  google.colab.kernel.invokeFunction('notebook.Concat', [message.position], {});
  //listener.unsubscribe();
});

''');
```

But I wasn't able to use it in Colab as after connecting and accessing the data for few minutes I experienced frequent runtime disconnects. I don't know whether it happens because of any security issues. So I was trying to move to Jupyter Notebook provided by Binder.

So I am trying to find an alternative for `eval_js` as in google colab. No solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63561206/14983808) worked for me.

Inspite of alternative I need to know How I can connect ROS using `roslibjs` with Binder notebooks.

Note: I am very new to javascript and I have not used or learnt it earlier. Google Colab runtime disconnect issues happened in Chromium,Chromium(Incognito) and Firefox(without any 3rd party plugins) as well also I didn't ran a ML model to use all of the Colab Resources.

**UPDATE**:
(12/07/23)

Without `eval_js` I was able to connect to rosbridge server by running the following script (as a HTML) in (Google Colab)

```
from IPython.display import Javascript, display, HTML

htm = """
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/roslib@1/build/roslib.js"></script>
<script>

// Connecting to ROS
// -----------------

var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({
  url : 'ws://localhost:9090'
});

ros.on('connection', function() {
  console.log('Connected to websocket server Hi da.');
});

ros.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log('Error connecting to websocket server: ', error);
});

ros.on('close', function() {
  console.log('Connection to websocket server closed.');
});

// Subscribing to a Topic
var listener = new ROSLIB.Topic({
  ros : ros,
  name : '/chatter',
  messageType : 'std_msgs/String'
});

listener.subscribe(function(message) {
  console.log('Received message on ' + listener.name + ': ' + message.data);
  //google.colab.kernel.invokeFunction('notebook.Concat', [message.data], {});
  //listener.unsubscribe();
});

</script>
"""
display(HTML(htm))
```

But when I tried the same in Binder's Jupyter Notebook it doesn't work even though I use IPython's display and HTML only.