# No output when using atpbar in a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, progress-bar, tqdm

Although quite a few people have had issues with viewing output from a Jupyter Notebook, I have not found any specific answer to why tqdm can output a progressbar just fine while atpbar https://pypi.org/project/atpbar/ cannot.

I have no idea why this is but it is really quite frustrating.

In short: this does not produce an output

```
from atpbar import atpbar
import time
import random
n = random.randint(1000, 10000)
for i in atpbar(range(n)):
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

while this does

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import time
import random
n = random.randint(1000, 10000)
for i in tqdm(range(n)):
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

Why is that?

Some clarification:

- On my local machine it works fine, when running under VS Code
- Running as a remote hosted jupyter note, it doesn't
- I am running a multithreaded workload, hence the need for atpbar

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49613135/5241172 I installed ipywidgets < 7.6 and atpbar now works as expected.